# trying to generate a report that would group by a header in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a unique report and I'm really struggling how I could do it. Here's an image to give an idea:

[image]

The report is has a parameter that I pass with a Client ID. I am able to pass multiple Client ID and I am hoping that this generate will display the correct data in a format that I hope to achieve.

let's say I enter ClientID 17,19:

- on the first page of Client 17, I want to be able to see content in the red border, below it i will have a tablix and some more stuff. The tablix will have a lot of data and will go to the 2nd page. On the 2nd page, I only want to see the content in the green border.
- For next client ID (19), I would again hope to see the content in the red border, and again, if the rest of the report goes to 2nd page, I would want to only see the content in green border.

Anyone have an idea?

I am able to create a report like this for just a single client, as I can make the PAGE HEADER not repeat on each page, and include the Organization: ABC COmpany and ClientName in the Tablix with the rest of the data.

But when it comes to doing multiple clients, I am struggling to make this work.

Comment: is something like that even doeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a table in your report that is grouped on your `ClientID` field.  This will initially give you one table row per `ClientID`.

You can then insert a new row inside the group.  This will give you two rows per `ClientID`.

In the top row, add everything in the red section from your question.  You can do this either by adding a sub-table into the textbox that has rows and columns formatted to display the Client's address details, or you can add in a Rectangle to allow free form placement of other report items like text boxes.

In the row below this one, do the same again.  Add in everything you would need to display your data as per your green section.

Comment: The problem here is that I cannot display the Red box content on the 2nd page, so since I will have two rows INSIDE groups, both static rows have to be displayed on every page, or not

Comment: No they don't...?  Your first row will be at the top of the table group and your second row, if more than one page tall, will spill onto the next page *without* the first row.  I don't think you are understanding that you can have a table within a table.  The second row would be one row of the top table, but would contain *all* the detail rows of the inner table.  Just try it and see what happens.